# Over time will bounty values rise higher and higher meaning the cost of entry to be too great?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Over the short time I have been apart of Stack Overflow I have been aiming towards getting enough points to add bounties to questions I haven't gotten answers for yet.

What I have noticed during this time is that bounty values in the featured list of stack overflow seem to be going up over time. This is anecdotal as I don't know where to get these statistics from.

Is there some mechanism in place which will stop the bounties getting too high so that people starting out like myself will be able to use them without the price of entry being too high? What is that point set at current?

Comment: BTW, the cap for a bounty is 500. This is a fair bit, but not unreasonable.

Comment: Understandable, its a community. Participation is a good thing. So I suppose my point goes more towards I am seeing the number of 250+ bounties rising (again anecdotal). If the limit is 500 and the majority get to a point where placing 500 on a question isn't a problem, how does anyone stand out?

Comment: We're seeing crap suggested edits which can reward the editor a lousy 2 reputation. Seems to me that 50 rep is still just fine for those who want to get to, say, 3k.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be seeing a higher number of high bounties, which would directly correlate with the sites having a larger user base over time - and an increasing number of them having huge amounts of reputation.

This doesn't stop you putting down bounties of 50 or 100 on your questions. You can still do that, and you will still receive responses.

You might be concerned that you might have to *compete* with the higher bounties... but you don't have to. There are *hundreds of thousands* of users here. The bountied questions cover topics *far and wide*. The people answering your question may not be going for the higher bounty questions. The people who answer higher bounty questions may still answer yours anyway - a bounty is a bounty.

**Go ahead and use bounties of 50 or 100 if you want to. Do not feel pressure to put a higher bounty on your questions.** You'll still get a response. It may even make your question less intimidating to bounty hunters than a bounty of, say, 400.

> Is there some mechanism in place which will stop the bounties getting too high so that people starting out like myself will be able to use them without the price of entry being too high? What is that point set at current?

As noted in comments: bounties currently can't go over 500. That upper limit is not likely to increase.